# Maya API(C++) - MayaApi to c++ did not work well

Tags: c++, maya, maya-api

I recently started studying Maya API.
When I tried to write in C++ with reference to the [Sample Command Plug-in](https://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2016/ENU/?guid=__files_GUID_85B1116E_F0C1_42AD_9CD4_30E936B6C7B8_htm), it did not work well
Build did well, but I don't know exactly what is wrong.
Could you help me?

```
#include <maya/MFnPlugin.h>
#include <maya/MPxCommand.h>
#include <maya/MArgList.h>

class myCommandName : public MPxCommand
{

public:
    MStatus     doIt(const MArgList&) override;
    static      void* creator();
};

MStatus myCommandName::doIt(const MArgList& args)
{
    return MS::kSuccess;
}

void* myCommandName::creator()
{
    return new myCommandName();
}


MStatus initializePlugin(MObject obj)
{
    MStatus   status;
    MFnPlugin plugin(obj, PLUGIN_COMPANY, "3.0");

    status = plugin.registerCommand("myCommandName", myCommandName::creator);
    if (!status) {
        status.perror("registerCommand");
        return status;
    }

    return status;
}

MStatus uninitializePlugin(MObject obj)
{
    MStatus   status;
    MFnPlugin plugin(obj);

    status = plugin.deregisterCommand("myCommandName");
    if (!status) {
        status.perror("deregisterCommand");
        return status;
    }

    return status;
}
```

Error:

```
// Error: file: C:/Program Files/Autodesk/Maya2019/scripts/others/pluginWin.mel line 317: initializePlugin function failed (myCommandName)
```

Comment: The error often is a hint that some libraries are missing. Did you compile in release mode?

Comment: No, I compiled in debug mode...

Comment: This could maybe the reason. Try to compile in release mode and use the recommended VisualStudio version for Maya2019. If you use newer platform toolset, you may have to provide the correct VC redistributables.

Comment: haggi krey-> Thank you! This code compiled successfully in release mode.